# Correct Sentence construction for Wh Question

Tags: questions, wh-questions

Is the Asking questions in below format is correct?

a) Where you brought all these vegetables from?

Comment: Do you mean buy, bought or bring, brought? Have you done any research on sentences with where or what or why or when?

Answer (score 2):

Not in Standard English. Main clause interrogatives like this require subject-auxiliary inversion: "Where did you bring all these vegetables from?" Note that the plain verb-form "bring" is required after the auxiliary verb "did".

<sup>(answer transcribed from comment)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The format of the question is not quite correct. You need to have:

- auxiliary verb + subject + verb

So, we would say:

> Where **did** (*aux verb*) **you** (*subject*) **bring** (*verb*) all these vegetables from?